# Something from GPUImageFilters remains in memory even after deallocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, opengl-es, gpuimage

I'm using GPUImage to do a bunch of image processing both in real time and on static images, I noticed that after churning through ~100 thumbnail images each of which has slightly different image processing done to each that there are still objects in memory after they're done processing and they're all related to GPUImageFilters:

**(Allocation lifespan is 'created & still living')**
[image]

You can see the memory spike from some processing I'm doing and after its done, on the other side of the mountain I have some stuff left in memory, I chose some 24KB blocks to examine (there are others). You can see on the right, the first item comes from GPUImageSoftLightBlendFilter, if I click on all 12 items each one comes from a GPUImageFilter (GPUImageHardLightBlendFilter, GPUImageMultiplyBlendFilter, etc).  Now if I do the same processing a second time, and expand the memory graph selection you'll see no NEW instances of these objects were made, its as if they took up space in memory once and just hang around:

[image]

Sure enough, if I change the memory graph selection to only show the second mountain you see that those line don't show up again because they weren't 'created & still living' again:

[image]

Why is this, I don't want the memory from these GPUImageFilter objects hanging around for the lifetime of my app running?  I put some logging in the GPUImageFilters to confirm they're being deallocated and dealloc is being called.

Comment: Could this be an issue with memory management in association with the GPU? Maybe an OpenGL ES structure is never being properly released.

Answer (score 1):

From code inspection of the GPUImage source, it looks like the `GLProgram` object from the last filter used remains set (and retained) by the shared `GPUImageContext`, which means that its corresponding OpenGL program objects also can't go away. However, the dealloc for the existing `GLProgram` implementation only marks the current program for deletion. Unlike `glDeleteTextures`, `glDeleteProgram` does not unbind the currently-bound program if it's the one being deleted, which means it can't be completely destroyed *yet*. Therefore, you probably have to make two changes:

1. Call `[GPUImageContext setActiveShaderProgram:nil]` to clear the current GLProgram binding, which releases the last reference to `GLProgram` and marks the current program for deletion.
2. Ensure that the program is unbound by calling `glUseProgram(0)`. You can either do this any number of ways:

   - Call it explicitly immediately after the call above, since the correct `EAGLContext` will already be bound.
   - Add the call to the body of `+[GPUImageContext setActiveShaderProgram:]`, either by adding it unconditionally above `[shaderProgram use]`, or by calling either `[shaderProgram use]` or `glUseProgram(0)` depending on whether `shaderProgram` is `nil`.
   - Have `-[GLProgram dealloc]` check whether or not it is the currently-bound program with `glGetIntegerv(GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM, &program)`, and unbinding itself if it is.

Comment: Nice, excited to try this out but I can't find any references to `GPUImageContext`, did you mean `GPUImageOpenGLESContext`?

Comment: Hokay, I ran `[GPUImageOpenGLESContext setActiveShaderProgram:nil]` and `glUseProgram(0)` in the dealloc of the ViewController that sets up these GPUImageFilters but it had no impact on the residual memory from GLEngine.  Dang.